# Script that loops after a random delay within an interval

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I want to make a loop that clicks, then sleeps for roughly half of a second (but not the exact same delay per iteration), then clicks again, then sleeps for roughly 50 seconds (same situation as before), then loops.

Here's what I whipped up but it doesn't work at all:

```
loop
{
Click
Sleep %var1%
Click
Sleep %var2%
}

down::
Pause
Return

Random, var2, 50853, 58179
Return

Random, var1, 412, 942
Return
```

Also, if you could figure out how to make it so a hotkey (something like alt + n) would stop the loop, then pressing the key again would RESET the loop, not resume it.

This script is supposed to be simulating a person double-clicking something then waiting just under a minute to do it again (For a game with macro detection)

Comment: Flicking rapid heal in nmz huh.

Comment: This man knows what's up lmao @0x464e

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're off to a good start! Unfortunately, if this is your full script, it would get stuck in the loop as soon as it gets loaded. In order to get a better understanding of the code below, you may want to read through the "Getting Started" section of the [help documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm), specifically [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

Please see if this works for you:

```
!n::
bToggle := !bToggle
If bToggle
    SetTimer , label_ClickLoop , -1
Return

label_ClickLoop:
Loop
{
    Random , var1 , 412 , 942
    Random , var2 , 50853 , 58179
    Click
    Sleep , var1
    Click
    Loop , 100
    {
        Sleep , var2 / 100
        If !bToggle
            Break , 2
}   }
MsgBox ,,, Loop cancelled! , 0.75
Return
```

Comment: Excellent. Works perfectly. Thank you!